# How to run installation scripts without allowing shutdown/reboot/hibernate

Tags: ssh, permissions, software-installation, sudo, reboot

I would like to run installation scripts on a remote server through SSH, but it is important that the server does not shutdown/reboot/hibernate. If I run a script using sudo, how can I prevent the script from telling the server to shutdown?

I am attempting to install programs on a computer which currently can only be accessed remotely. The drive is encrypted and the encryption key can only be entered in person, so it is important the computer does not restart for the time being so it can be accessed remotely. How would I run scripts to install software from the terminal in such a way that it will allow root access but abort if it needs to restart after installing?

Answer (score 0):

Updating, but never rebooting is a dangerous system management technique.

I've found, on several Ubuntu releases up to 18.04, that, after updating my remote systems with

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade
```

I must check the files `/var/run/reboot*`, which, if they exist, will contain "reasons" why I should reboot. My process is to reboot only if `/var/run/reboot*` exists (and no system admin reasons discourage reboots, except SECURITY!).

If the update is done manually, you don't have to reboot.

Over time, more and more components of your system will mismatch the running, unupdated kernel. This will lead to hard-to-diagnose problems for future you.